# Blank URL box appears in the footer section of Google Chromium Print PDF Preview in Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, raspberry-pi, chromium, raspbian

[image: Print dialog]

In the above picture there is an empty Http text box appearing in the footer section of the PDF Print Preview Dialog Box. This happens only when we try to take a print using Raspberry Pi's Chromium browser. This doesn't happen when we use Google Chrome from Ubuntu or any other OS. I have also disabled the Headers and footers option from the print dialog box and still this didn't go. I tried to find the fix to this issue online but could not find any. Any Help would be appreciated. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who gets this error in future, I have figured out the answer to this issue. I was getting this error because I had installed Virtual Keyboard on Chromium. Uninstalling the virtual keyboard removes the blank URL box from Print PDF Preview.